# Highcharts chart sometimes appears squashed

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

Sometimes (about 15% of the time) my highcharts chart doesn't load properly and displays like this:

[image: squashed highcharts image]

I'll then adjust the browser window size and it fixes itself and appears correctly.

[image: highcharts chart displaying correctly]

I have a hunch that it maybe does this because I have assigned the chart a percentage width and not a static width. I would like to keep it as a percentage width.

Any ideas on how I can get around this problem?

Comment: I had the same issue. Use **@media screen** css rules to make static widths for most of the page widths. It's much like creating a responsive grid resembling bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah, the concern is it will be deployed to a couple of websites which have different widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following breakpoints. The last three are from bootstrap and the first one is a bonus.

```
@media screen and (min-device-width:230px){
    .chart{
        width:230px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width:768px){
    .chart{
        width:768px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width:992px){
    .chart{
        width:992px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width:1200px){
    .chart{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

+1 if it helps.